# How can I access my desktop from root shell prompt in recovery menu?

Tags: boot, command-line, login, root

I updated graphics drivers today, which unfortunately causes a black screen at login. I want to access my desktop so I can copy certain files off the laptop while I figure out a fix, but I'm unable to open a terminal at login using Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Booting in recovery mode, I can select the "root"  option to drop to a root shell prompt. From here, I can login to my user account through:

su --login myuser

...where I get a message that says "No directory,  logging in with HOME=/". However, I cannot change directories to my Desktop, which should be located at /home/myuser/Desktop/. I can cd into the home directory, but it appears like there's nothing in it. Any thoughts on how to access my Desktop through the root shell?

Comment: It's <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F1>... don't use <Shift>.

Comment: Right sorry, that was a typo.  I have been using Ctrl+Alt+F1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, when you boot into recovery mode, the home partition will not mount automatically.

First locate your home partition using commands like: `lsblk` or `fdisk -l` or even by having a look at `/etc/fstab`:

```
# grep '/home' /etc/fstab | grep ext
```

Then mount that partition at `/home` (in my case `sda2` is my home partition).

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /home
```

And copy your file to your desired path, device.

*Remember that you may need to remount or mount your partitions with `rw` option.*

Comment: If `/home` has a valid `/etc/fstab` entry it should be sufficient to type `mount /home` (or alternatively just `mount -a`)

Comment: That would do the work too ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! For me, I ran the following commands to mount the home directory:                                                                                             mount --options remount,rw /                                                                 mount --all                                                                                                             This allowed me to access my files as I'm used to.